# How to print scroll-able panel in windows form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, screenshot

i have custom control which has one scrollable panel, which entire content is not visible on screen.(Need to scroll to see all content)

User wants to print the panel exactly how it looks on screen but user wants entire panel which is not visible on screen without scrolling.

How to capture and print whole panel in multiple pages?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of how it looks and your code ? more information would be useful in determining exactly what you are trying to do

Answer (score -1):

this may help you.

```
    pnlReport.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, 0);

    public void DrawControl(Control control, Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        control.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, control.Bounds);
        foreach (Control childControl in control.Controls)
        {
            DrawControl(childControl, bitmap);
        }
    }


    public void SaveBitmap(string filename)
    {
        var size = myControl.PreferredSize;
        var height = size.Height;
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(this.myControl.Width, height);

        this.myControl.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.myControl.Width, height));
        foreach (Control control in myControl.Controls)
        {
            DrawControl(control, bmp);
        }

        bmp.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        bmp.Dispose();
    }
```